# CUPS: silent authentication printing

Tags: linux, authentication, cups

Under Debian Buster, I am looking for a solution to print with CUPS but without having to provide the password each time. Under Windows, I just had to enter the credentials for the desired printer port and when printing it no longer asked for a password.

How to do the same in Debian?

For information, for the sake of traceability, each user is authenticated by an account created on the CUPS server and our printers are not directly visible. You have to go through the CUPS server redirected by the **/etc/cups/client.conf** file of each client with the **ServerName** directive and pre-populated when printed by the **User** directive.

Comment: Looks like this can be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/57493/save-print-server-authentication-credentials

Comment: @Sandeep that suggests removing the authentication. This question seems to presuppose the authentication and is asking how to cope with it. (But I could be wrong!)

Comment: Thank you for your answers; It's exactly that ! We need to know who prints what to avoid drifts and waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution.

Printer's URI must looks like this : ipp://USER:PASSWD@CUPS_SERVER:631/printers/PRINTER

ex : ipp://lnj:1234@cups.local:631/printers/KONICA_MINOLTA_C280

Nota : with CUPS' default configuration, printers are available here : http://localhost:631/printers

See also [this thread (in French)](https://forums.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-37325629-cups-authentification-silencieuse-a-l-impression#12)

So problem solved !